# Why is it better to use Angular service on API calls?

Tags: angular, http, service

When making HTTP calls or API calls to the backend, what does Angular service do and why is it beneficial to use it?

Comment: When you use Angular Services for API calls you can call those API calls from any component in your Angular Application.

Comment: As opposed to what?

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils not opposed to something, just generally why choose Angular service to handle API calls and HTTP requests.

Comment: @SamTulster. Imagine at first you get the data from a static array, after from a file, after for a dbs, after, decided that if you has no conexion to internet get the data from localStore... Each change only need change how the "service" get the data else you need look for all the components that get the call and change the component. It's more "modular" and more easy -even for test- use a service.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As described in the [Angular documentation](https://angular.io/guide/architecture-services), the purpose of componenents is as follows:

> Ideally, a component's job is to enable the user experience and
>   nothing more. A component should present properties and methods for
>   data binding, in order to mediate between the view (rendered by the
>   template) and the application logic (which often includes some notion
>   of a model).

On the very next paragraph, the purpose of services is explained:

> A component can delegate certain tasks to services, such as fetching
>   data from the server, validating user input, or logging directly to
>   the console. By defining such processing tasks in an injectable
>   service class, you make those tasks available to any component. You
>   can also make your app more adaptable by injecting different providers
>   of the same kind of service, as appropriate in different
>   circumstances.

On software engineering terms, this conforms to the **Singleton** pattern. In Angular, the standard practice when it comes to defining and creating services is to provide them at the root level, followed by creating a shared instance of the service, which can be injected into other classes/components that require it.

On your service files, you may notice the `@Injectable()` decorator, which may look something like this:

```
@Injectable()
export class SampleService {

  // other things within your service

}
```

This denotes the class as a 'service', which will tell Angular to inject it to other components as a dependency. You may read more about dependency injection over [here](https://angular.io/guide/architecture-services#dependency-injection-di).